# What's the best practice to store variables for Cucumber tests?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

What's the best practice to store variables for Cucumber tests?

I'm using Cucumber and Capybara to test a Java application.

In the application there are many types of users and other data that I need to pass into my Capybara step definitions. So my question is what is the best practice to store these variables/users IDs?

I do have some variables (@instance_variabless) that I've stored all in the env.rb file.

But is there a more clean/elegant way to do this? Like have a dedicated file just for variables that I can call, if so how would such a file be setup?

Please provide examples of solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) for set-up and tear-down in `hooks.rb` file:

```
@user_ids_and_passwords = YAML.load(File.open('features/config/users.yml'))

@my_heavy_object = HeavyObject.new
@my_heavy_object.do_it

at_exit do
  @my_heavy_object.undo_it
end

AfterConfiguration do |config|
  puts "Features dwell in #{config.feature_dirs}"
  @instance_variable = 'my variable'
end

Before('@some_features') do
  @feature_instance_variable = 'something else'
end
```

Comment: Would this work for lets say 50 different user types (50 unique user ids/pws)? How would that be structured in that file?

Comment: I would put it in a configuration file (a YAML perhaps?) and read it - see my update

Comment: So once I load the YAML file, then whatever is in there can be used, if it's not loaded I can't use it? 
Also whats the best type of variables I should make these userids? They will be used in various different Cuke feature files.

Comment: Do you wanna answer still ?